# Ajax modal submit parse json response for errors in form, error message repeating itself over both fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I've got a modal window that is submitting a form to a database via ajax and if an error occurs it will return a json response. This has been working well on modal windows with only one input field, but I have another modal window with 2 fields and the json response correctly returns error messages, for instance:

[image: json response]

As you can see, both fields with the error are in the response. Like I said, my script works fine and will show the error for a form with only one text input, but I have two in this form (ignore the first select element, it is pre-filled via ajax). Here's my script that handles the ajax success and error responses:

```
$(document).ready(function () //function to process modal form via ajax
{
    $('.modal-submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit action

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var type = $(this).find('input[name="type"]').val(); //get value of hidden input
        var url = $(this).attr('action'); //get action from form
        var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
        var modalInput = $(this).find('.form-row input'); //get input from form
        var modalId = $(this).closest('.modal').attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            method:'POST',
            data:data,
            success:function(response){
                refreshData(newId = response.id, modalId); // set newId to the id of the newly inserted item, get modalId
                modal.modal('hide'); //hide modal
                $(modalInput).val(''); //clear input value
            },
            error:function(response){
                $.each(response.responseJSON.error, function (i, error) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(response.responseJSON.error);
                    $(modalInput).addClass('input-error');
                    $('#' + modalId + ' .backend-error').html(error[0]); //return error from backend
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the html for the modal window with multiple inputs:

```
<!-- Add New Model Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modelModalLabel">Add new asset model</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" class="modal-submit" autocomplete="off" action="{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'model']) }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="model">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputManufacturerModel">Manufacturer *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select name="inputManufacturerModel" id="inputManufacturerModel" class="form-control" required="required" onclick="refreshData()">
                                <option value="0">Select manufacturer...</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputModelNew">New model name *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="inputModelNew" id="inputModelNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Add manufacturer model name" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="backend-error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputModelNoNew">New model # *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="inputModelNoNew" id="inputModelNoNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Add manufacturer model #" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="backend-error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- / Add New Model Modal -->
```

Result of error response:

[image]

Do I need to loop over the errors? How do I get the relevant error to show under the correct input field?

Comment: You need to give specific element. It write last error all ".backend-error" element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ajax error don't use this 
 **$(modalInput).addClass('input-error')** because this will add the class to all modal's input and this will set the error to all modal's input. **$('#' + modalId + ' .backend-error').html(error[0]);**

Use input Id to set error like in your case **$('#inputModelNew').parent('.input-group').siblings('.backend-error').addClass('input-error').html(error[0])**